# Lua - How would I spoof the GetFenv function, without changing it?

Tags: security, lua

I have some code I would like to find a vulnerability in, I coded it, and I would be grateful if you could help me out with finding anything in it.

My one and only concern are that getfenv may be able to be spoofed, in some way.

```
coroutine.wrap(function()
    while wait() do
        for i, v in func_table.pairs(func_table) do
            if func_table.getfenv()[i] ~= v then
                return ban_func(10, 23)
            end
        end
    end
end)()
```

To be clear, the ban_func is inside the func_table, this will automatically detect its change in data and will ban accordingly. The only way I think they, being the exploiter/cheater, would be able to change anything is by spoofing getfenv.

If you could explain to me how it would be possible to spoof such a function and/or how to patch a spoof on the function, all without changing any of its own data, I would be very happy!

Comment: Can your write into `func_table`?

Comment: ? The exploiters/cheaters can edit upvalues / the registry, which is why I added the ban function into the func_table, those values include tables, functions, user data, strings. I might want

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this code is running on the exploiter/cheaters machine. Fundamentally, there is no way to guarantee security of client code. Your checks can be removed, and your checks checks can be removed. Even the Lua binary itself can be changed internally and the getfenv can be changed to do anything in addition to what it does. Implementing a strong border between server and client logic is the only true way to secure applications.

One attack possible in this case is if the client runs Lua code in the same lua_State before your func_table is setup. In this case, they could sandbox you like my lua sandbox implementation found [here](https://github.com/TylerRHoyer/RBXLua-Sandbox/blob/master/sandbox.lua).

Another attack is taking advantage of metamethods to make `func_table.getfenv()[i] ~= v` return true. This could be detected by using rawequal, checking the type of `func_table.getfenv()[i]`, or using the original functions as keys in a table of true values and checking if the table at key `func_table.getfenv()[i]` is true.

Yet another attack would be to edit both the global state and your table. It is common when changing the address of a function, to change ALL references to that address in ram, which would include the internal reference inside your table.

Since you are using `wait()` I assume that you are running this code in Roblox. In that case, as I've emphasized on their developer forums, the `experimental mode` (previously `filtering enabled`) setting is the only way to secure your game from exploiters. This prevents clients from editing the game most of the time. They still have full control of their character position, a couple other instance types (like Hats I believe), can ask the server to make changes through RemoteEvent and RemoteFunction instances, and wall hack (set wall transparency) (to counter this, only send client parts that It can see).